# How to enable logging in mysql driver

Tags: java, mysql, logging, jdbc

How to enable logging in mysql j connector driver?

I used the following command while creating the connection

```
"jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?logger=com.mysql.jdbc.log.StandardLogger&profileSQL=true";
```

My log4j property file is like this

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE,  rfile
log4j.logger.com.mysql=trace, rfile
log4j.appender.rfile = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rfile.File =PrepStmt.log
log4j.appender.rfile.MaxFileSize = 100KB
log4j.appender.rfile.Append = true
log4j.appender.rfile.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rfile.layout.ConversionPattern= %d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

No log is getting captured in my log file.

Comment: Direct Log4J logging was dropped from version  3.1.1 of Connector/J

Answer (score 1):

Mysql does not know about your log4j properties.

From the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html), scroll to section *Debugging/Profiling*:

> logger
>
> The name of a class that implements "com.mysql.jdbc.log.Log" that will
>   be used to log messages to. (default is
>   "com.mysql.jdbc.log.StandardLogger", which logs to STDERR)
>
> Default: com.mysql.jdbc.log.StandardLogger

So your mysql logs simply go to STDERR. If you want to log to a log4j defined destination you can implement `com.mysql.jdbc.log.Log`, forward to a log4j logger, and specify that implementation class in the connect URL.

Comment: Hi I tried following you comment and implemented `com.mysql.jdbc.log.Log` then I specified my class (fully qualified path) `jdbc.JdbcLogger` in connection url. However I get class not found exception from `com.mysql.jdbc.log.LogFactory` line 66 since it can not load this class. I can load the the class separately though using `Class.forName("jdbc.JdbcLogger)`. Using mysql-connector-java-5.1.38. Any idea what may be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You could configure [log4jdbc](https://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/) to intercept the JDBC connection and log the sql.